# Sefer Nachal Eshkol - Tzidkat HaTzaddik - Rabbi Binyomin Hersh Aurbach

Tags: history, rabbis, jewish-books

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Hirsch_Auerbach) there seems to be a conterversy as to whether the Sefer Nachal Eshkol is a forgery. Four Rabanim from Germany wrote Tzidkas HaTzadik to defend Rabbi Auerbach.

> Four prominent German rabbis (David Zvi Hoffmann, Abraham Berliner,
>   Jacob Schor and Hanokh Ehrentreu) wrote a booklet published in Berlin
>   in 1910 containing a defense of Auerbach named Tzidkat HaTzaddik

Where can one can obtain this defense of Rabbi Auerbach?

Comment: It is important to note that the defense was pretty much "he was a rabbi so he must not be a forger". However, the evidence speaks for itself. Numerous rabbinic greats such as R. Chaim Heller, long ago identified it as a forgery, and the evidence in the last century has piled up. The nail is in the coffin of the Auerbach Eshkol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The work is available online as free PDF on Hebrewbooks.org [here](http://hebrewbooks.org/39364).